# javascript prototype and "this" access in closure

Tags: javascript, object, closures

I am a beginner in js, and am puzzled by the following code:

```
Foo = function(arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
};

Foo.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        var f = function () {
            alert("current arg: " + this.arg); // am expecting "bar", got undefined
        }
        f();
    }
};

var yo = Foo("bar");
yo.init();
```

I was expected to get "current arg: bar", but got "current arg: undefined". I noticed that by copying this.arg into a "normal" variable first, and refering this variable in the closure works:

```
Foo.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        var yo = this.arg;
        var f = function () {
            alert("current arg: " + yo);            }
        f();
    }
};
```

Am I doing something wrong, got wrong expectations, or does it fall into one of the js WTF ?

Comment: Copying `this.arg` into a "normal" variable first won't do anything different to what `this` means for your function.

Comment: @bobobobo Technically true, but when did anyone imply that would happen?  The way you phrased that could be misleading.  He did not in fact use `this` in the second example; using the local variable `yo` creates a closure that keeps the reference to the intended object even inside the `f` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the function was invoked.

If invoked with keyword `new` then `this` refers to the object being constructed (which will be implicitly returned at the end of the function).

If invoked as a normal function, `this` refers to the global `window` object.

Example:

```
// Constructor for Foo,
// (invoke with keyword new!)
function Foo()
{
  this.name = "Foo" ;
}

myFoo = new Foo() ;
alert( 'myFoo ' + myFoo.name + '\n' + 'window: ' + window.name ) ; // window.name will be empty

// now if we invoke Foo() WITHOUT keyword NEW
// then all references to `this` inside the
// function Foo will be to the
// __global window object__, i.e. the global window
// object will get clobbered with new properties it shouldn't
// have! (.name!)

Foo() ;  // incorrect invokation style!
alert( 'myFoo ' + myFoo.name + '\n' + 'window: ' + window.name ) ;
```

JavaScript doesn't have "constructors" per se, the only way JavaScript knows that your `function` is actually a "constructor" is invokation style (namely you using keyword `new` whenever you invoke it)

Answer (score 4):

Vanilla functions will be run with `this` referring to `window`. Your second piece of code is a perfect example of how to work around this problem using closures.

(You can also use `call` and `apply` to call a function with a particular context.)

Comment: It's too bad downvotes are anonymous. To whomever downvoted, I'd appreciate a comment :)